# cant understand why n0 isnt 1 in this big-O definition?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

So I've been solving this exercise that asks to prove by big-O definition

```
2^(2log(n)) = O(n^2)
```

so I realized that `2^(2log(n)) = n^2`
and i found out that c = 1 and n0 = 1 because `n^2 <= 1*n^2` starts from n >=1
but why at the answer the teacher chose n0 = 2 ?

does it matter? or it can be 1 also?

is there any trick to find c and n0 easily in these kind of questions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly noticed, they are exactly equal using logarithmic rules / power rules, thus we can choose `c=1` and some arbitrary `n0` because the definition asks for `n0>0` such that for **all** `n>n0`:
`n^2 <= c*n^2 = n^2`. And of-course it is true for all values of `n0`.

So it does not matter if your teacher chose `n0=2` or you chose `n0=1`, you are both correct by definition.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition of Big O:

> f(n) = O(g(n)) if there exists a positive integer n0 and a positive constant c, such that f(n) ≤ c*g(n) ∀ n≥n0

From your question, it is unclear of what the **base value** of `log` function is?

Let `f(n) = 2^(2log(n))` and `g(n) = n^2`.

Let us consider 3 following cases:

**Case 1:** `base = 2`

`f(n)` evaluates to `n^2` and therefore it is clear that `c=1` and `n0=1`.

**Case 2:** `base = 10`

`f(n)` = `2^(2log10(n))` ~ `n^(0.602)`

In this case, we can also say that `c=1` and `n0=1`.

**As a proof**, I plotted the graph for the functions `x^2` and `x^0.602` as follows:

[image]

In the above figure, you can clearly see that for `n0 > 1`, the `x^2 > x^0.602`.

**Case 3:** `base = e`

`f(n)` = `2^(2loge(n))` ~ `n^(1.3862)`

In this case as well, we can say that `c=1` and `n0=1`.

**As a proof**, I plotted the graph for the functions `x^2` and `x^1.3862` as follows:

[image]

**Therefore, in all the cases, you are correct.**

**PS:** There is a strong possibility that you and professor are assuming different value for the base of the logarithmic function. But in that case as well, if `base>=2`, I don't see there is any wrong to consider `n0=1`.